# Javascript/HTML5 - Save mute on localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, button, audio, local-storage

I'm creating 5 games with javascript and html5 and I'm using sound. I have a mute button that activates the function down bellow. Thing is, I want to make so that if I press the mute button and I move to another page, it will still be muted, but I can't seem to figure out how to integrate it in this function. If someone could help me out by editing the code, I'd really apreciate it :D

```
function init(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "sound/paint_Music.mp3";
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.autoplay = true;

    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);

function mute(){
    if (audio.muted){
        audio.muted = false;
        document.getElementById("mutebtn").src = "img/soundON.png";
    } else {
        audio.muted = true;
        document.getElementById("mutebtn").src = "img/soundOFF.png";


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your function like this

```
function init() {
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "sound/paint_Music.mp3";
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.autoplay = true;
    var muteState = localStorage.getItem('muteState');
    if (!muteState || muteState !== 'true') {
        audio.muted = false;
        document.getElementById("mutebtn").src = "img/soundON.png";
    }
    else {
        audio.muted = true;
        document.getElementById("mutebtn").src = "img/soundOFF.png";
    }
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);

    function mute() {
        if (audio.muted) {
            audio.muted = false;
            document.getElementById("mutebtn").src = "img/soundON.png";
        } else {
            audio.muted = true;
            document.getElementById("mutebtn").src = "img/soundOFF.png";
        }
        localStorage.setItem('muteState', String(audio.muted));
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help.
That was almost perfect for what I wanted. The sound gets muted on the next page if I press the mute button, but, the function mute also changes the source of the image, so when the sound is muted, it shows one image (soundOFF) and when it's not it shows another image (soundON). Thing is, when I hit mute and enter the next page, the sound is muted, but it shows me the wrong image. Do you know how I could change that?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! Exactly what I wanted! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Add the muted value to your `localStorage` in your 'mute' method.

```
function mute(){
        ...
        audio.muted = false;
        localStorage.setItem('muted', 'false');
    } else {
        audio.muted = true;
        localStorage.setItem('muted', 'true');
    }
}
```

}

Then on your `init` retrieve the `localStorage` value or default to `false` if it wasn't set prior.

```
function init(){
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "sound/paint_Music.mp3";
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.autoplay = true;
    var isMuted = (localStorage.getItem("muted") && localStorage.getItem("muted") == 'true') || false

    audio.muted = isMuted;
    mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
    mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("muted")` => `"false"` => `true` which does not always produce the desired result. In other words, non-empty strings are implicitly converted to `true` regardless of their contents

Comment: Thank you for the help. But with this, the audio is always muted when the page loads :s